# ReactJS navigate to new location & refresh window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use a ReactJs to create a single component, a dynamic form, after the user successfuly sends the form I need to:

1. Redirect away from the form
2. Full refresh of the window to get new html templates. Here I don't care for any React state. In this new location there is no React present (the component is only in one location).

So far I tried with replacing history, that caused a redirect but not a request to the server to retrieve those new html templates. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I understand is correct, you want to redirect to a new page once the form is submitted. Also you want the new page to be rendered from Server Side.

Try this:

```
onFormSubmit() {
    // ... do things

    window.location.assign("http://exampleapp.com/somepage/");
}
```